# How can I integrate caliper benchmark tool with my hyperledger fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, caliper

I have developed a system using Hyperledger Fabric peer version 2.2.2 hence I need to test the performance (i.e. latency, throughput etc.) of this system  using Hyperledger Caliper. I'm new with Blockchain and found it hard to integrate my network with Caliper! Which version of caliper will be suitable for fabric 2.2.2? How can I carry out this whole integration procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This linked [tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGi17lErgf0&list=PLSBNVhWU6KjXRadn0Cezi5mCbLMXzjewX) on youtube will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use caliper 0.4.2 as this supports 2.2.2. I would suggest you follow the tutorial first here https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/fabric-tutorial/tutorials-fabric-existing/

As you have created your own fabric network you should be able to construct your own appropriate connection profiles which caliper requires.

If you plan to run caliper on a different machine to the one that contains your network then be aware of the need to disable the localhost default of true as described in the runtime settings on this page https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/fabric-config/new/#introducing-the-new-fabric-connector.